# How to pass id and name of a @Html.CheckBox via form collection in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is my html-

```
<td>
   @{
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Brands = ViewBag.GetBrands;
     foreach (var item in Brands)
       {                                                                   
         @Html.CheckBox(item.Text, false)                                                                                                                                                                                 
         <label>@item.Text</label><br />
       }
    }
</td>
```

Im Posting this controller as JSON data (form collection). How can i get checkbox's `text` and `value` in form collection data in controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284395/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-view-and-get-the-checked-items-passed-to-the-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get ID by -

```
@Html.CheckBox(item.Text, false, new {item.Value})
```

Comment: try @Html.CheckBox(item.Text, false, new {id="myCheckbox"})  I did something similar with CheckBoxFor() and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get checkbox's text and value in form collection data in controller?

The correct approach is to use a view model instead of this `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. So basically your model could look like this:

```
public class BrandViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

and then add a property to your main view model (the one your view is strongly typed to) of type `IList<BrandViewModel>`:

```
public IList<BrandViewModel> Brands { get; set; }
```

and then it's pretty easy:

```
<td>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Brands.Count; i++)
    {                                                                   
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Brands[i].Checked)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Brands[i].Checked, Model.Brands[i].Text)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Brands[i].Text)
    }
</td>
```

and finally you can get rid of any weakly typed FormCollection from your controller action and simply take the view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(IList<BrandViewModel> brands)
{
    ...
}
```

or if there are also other properties you need to pass your controller action may take the main view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MainViewModel model)
{
    // the model.Brands collection will be automatically bound here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to MVC checkboxes with none boolean values, it seems to work really well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to perform post back to server.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionname", "controller",
                    FormMethod.Post))
//your code
@{
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Brands = ViewBag.GetBrands;
     foreach (var item in Brands)
       {                                                                   
         @Html.CheckBox(item.Text, false)                                                                                                                                                                                 
         <label>@item.Text</label><br />
       }
    }
<input type="submit" class="k-button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" />
}
```

Now in the controller you will get the values using form collection

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult actionName( FormCollection collection)
{

collection.keys["checkbox"].value ... your code
}
```