# Returning Checkbox Values to Controller MVC4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

This question is quite closely linked to: [CheckboxList in MVC3 View and get the checked items passed to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284395/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-view-and-get-the-checked-items-passed-to-the-controller)

I am relativly new to MVC so please bear with me :)

I have brought into a page search results based on a query, and I want to allow the user to refine these results based on Locations and Sectors. I want to try and use Checkboxes for this, however I am having difficulty bringing the values of the checkboxes back into the controller for my update search action.

I have tried to follow the example in the question a labelled above, however I have had to expand on it a little to also incorpreate my search results etc and now I cannot get any of the results - hopefully it is something simple someone will point out however I have spent the best part of a day or two trying to figure it out with no joy.

The Model:

```
public class IndexViewModel : PagedView
{
    public enum ResultType
    {
        Business,
        Pitch,
        User
    }

    public string Query { get; set; }

    public int? Page { get; set; }

    public int? Show { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Result> BusinessResults { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LocationSearchModel> Locations { get; set; }

    public class Result
    {
        ...
    }

    public class LocationSearchModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As in the original, I referenced an EditorTemplate in the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Refine", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.EditorForModel("LocationSearchModel", Model)
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Update" />
            }
```

And my EditorTemplate, LocationSearchModel.cshtml, looks like:

```
@model UpInvestments.Web.Models.Search.IndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LocationSearchModel";
}

@foreach (var loc in Model.Locations)
{
    // Those two hidden fields are just to persist the id and name
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => loc.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => loc.Name)
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => loc.IsChecked)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => loc.IsChecked, loc.Name)
    </div>
}
```

Now I suspect the issue in possibly in what I am trying to put in my controller, I currently have:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(IndexViewModel queryModel)
        {
            var paging = queryModel.ToQueryPage();
            Services.BusinessSearch.SearchModel businessSearchModel = new SearchModel(Maybe.FromNullable(queryModel.Query), paging);
            ......
        }
```

I have tried a number of different options here but cannot seem to get any to work, in this example, which I thought would be the correct one, Locations within queryModel, which is my IEnumerable of Location results, is null, and I was hoping here it would tell me which items the user has checked and unchecked etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Add a breakpoint to `var paging = queryModel.ToQueryPage();`.  Run the app and check a box.  On the breakpoint, what does `queryModel.Locations` look like?  Is there an entry that's checked?

Comment: queryModel.Locations is null, it doesnt seem to return any of the locations that I originally pass into the model. There should be about 8 locations in there at the moment also.

Comment: I usually use Request.Form["checkboxlistname"].ToString() to get my check boxes back.  that will return 1,2,5, the id's of all of the check boxes that were checked on the form

Comment: @MattBodily Thanks, that certainly helps me for now and gets me by, although I would still be intrigued to know how I can get the full locations back without having to match up Id's to results etc.