# How can I put a Treelist on a frontend page to allow users to select Sitecore content items? (C#)

Tags: c#, tree, telerik, sitecore, treelist

I'm working on a tool that exports content from Sitecore, and one of the options asks the user to put in the path or ID of the start item. For example, the user can enter /sitecore/content/Home/MyPage. To make it more user friendly, I want to replace the text box with a tree view of the Sitecore content tree that allows the user to click on an item in the tree to select it as the starting node, the way the Treelist fields work in Sitecore.

[image]

I know that Telerik is used for this, but I have no idea how to begin implementing it in my own code. Can someone point me to how to get started?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to use the same control that is used in the Sitecore Content Editor or would you be ok with an alternative solution such as a list of checkboxes for each item in Sitecore that the user can select?

Comment: I'm fine with an alternate solution!

Comment: That's a good idea, I can probably figure out how to do something like that now that you mention it, though if there's a particular tool in mind that already does that that would be awesome. Don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I would just use standard Razor code to generate the list of checkboxes like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20687405/195335.

Comment: I would probably just use Sitecor Powershell Extensions, which will allow you to configure dialogs with numerous options to request input from users: http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2017/06/export-sitecore-item-data-using-sitecore-powershell.html