# using a list as the Model in an MVC view and binding the list items to controls

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

In Umbraco / MVC, my model is inheriting from a list of a custom model MyCustomModel,

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<List<MyCustomModel>>
```

That model contains a bool which I want to bind to a checkbox using @HTML.CheckBoxFor.
Normally if the model was not a list I would do this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.isSelected)
```

But as it is a list I have

```
 @foreach (MyCustomModel _model in Model)
 {
    <label>@_module.ItemName</label>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @_model.isSelected)
 }
```

Although this shows the correct data as it is on the page load, when I then iterate through the list model after checking some checkboxes, nothing has actually changed.

I think I may be able to do it using the index of the current item, something like

```
x => x[i].isSelected
```

How would I do this properly?

Comment: Have you tried this with multiple records?

Comment: Yes, the model/list I'm testing with currently has around 20 items

Comment: Yes, add the index to the binding: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.x[i].isSelected)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687121/asp-net-mvc-checkboxlist-from-model-with-list-property