# Null error when passing checkbox value from view to controller MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass the values of checkboxs from view to controller.
here are my code

In model:

```
public partial class ORDER_HEADER_INFO
{
   //many other fields 
    public bool checkExport { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void ExportCSV(List<Models.ORDER_HEADER_INFO> model) {
        foreach (Models.ORDER_HEADER_INFO item in model) {
              if (item.checkExport) {
                 //Do somethings
              }
         }
```

In View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TIS.Models.ORDER_HEADER_INFO>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportCSV", "MKP_004", FormMethod.Post)){
  <input type="submit" value="ExportCSV" />
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {DateTime deadline = new DateTime(2015, 04, 12);
        var className = (item.PRODUCT_START_DATE >= deadline) ? "selected" : null;
        <tr class="@className">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.ORDER_NO, "MKP_003", "MKP_003", new { id = item.ORDER_NO }, new { })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MODEL)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PJNO)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DELIVERY_DESTINATION)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PRODUCT_START_DATE)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FINISH_FLAG)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.checkExport)
            </td>
        </tr>        
    }
</table>
}
```

My expected outcome is i can get the list of selected items then do some work with them. In parameter of the method. I had tried:

```
List<Models.ORDER_HEADER_INFO> model
```

and

```
IEnumerable<TIS.Models.ORDER_HEADER_INFO> model
```

but when i debug the **model** is still null.

Many thanks!

Comment: Your `foreach` loop is generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and `name` attributes (which can't be bound to a collection) for the checkboxes. Use a `for` loop of a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `ORDER_HEADER_INFO` - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[0].checkExport) }` Inspect the html before and after to see the difference

Comment: When i use for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) there is a notice that Operator "<" can not be applied to operands of type "int" and "method group"

Comment: Make the model `@model IList<TIS.Models.ORDER_HEADER_INFO>` (or `List<...>`)

Comment: How can i replace this "item.PRODUCT_START_DATE". Sorry, I'm totally new with MVC 4

Comment: Exactly the same way - inside the `for` loop - `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[0].PRODUCT_START_DATE)` (dreadful naming BTW - follow convention and use ProductStartDate). But you have other problems as well. Your model has a property named `MODEL` and you have also named the parameter in your method `model` so binding will fail (you need to change one or the other)

Comment: I try to change code to be List and IList, now It passed all the model from view to controller. Can you tell me the difference between List, IList and IEnumberable

Comment: Suggest you research that yourself [IList vs IEnumerable](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ilist%20vs%20ienumerable)

Comment: @TranDuyLinh, like Stephen Muecke suggestion use for loop instead of foreach. I think this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22497568/2501044

Comment: See this SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you simply need to rewrite your `foreach` to be a `for` loop so that it applies indexing to the `name` attributes of the HTML fields, in order for the model binder to do it's work. Change your `foreach` to be:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{DateTime deadline = new DateTime(2015, 04, 12);
    var className = (Model[i].PRODUCT_START_DATE >= deadline) ? "selected" : null;
    <tr class="@className">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(Model[i].ORDER_NO, "MKP_003", "MKP_003", new { id = Model[i].ORDER_NO }, new { })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Model)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PJNO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].DELIVERY_DESTINATION)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PRODUCT_START_DATE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].FINISH_FLAG)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].checkExport)
        </td>
    </tr>        
}
```