# Getting Checkbox Value and Text in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Model**

```
public class AllControls
{
    public List<Group> getChkItems { get; set; }
    public bool chk { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{       
    List<Group> li = new List<Group>()
    {
        new Group() { ID = 1, Name = "C#" },
        new Group() { ID = 1, Name = "Asp.NET" },
        new Group() { ID = 1, Name = "SQL" }
    };

    AllControls model = new AllControls();
    model.getChkItems = li;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AllControls e)
{
    return View(e);
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var x in @Model.getChkItems)
    {    
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.chk, new { value = @x.ID }) @x.Name
        <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn" />    
}
```

How can I get the selected checkbox value and text in the controller?

Comment: you really don't need value on `Post`, you need only `ID`, if you still need text, you should put it in `hidden` hield (`Html.Hidden` helper). I suppose you still have problems with model binding on `Post`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284395/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-view-and-get-the-checked-items-passed-to-the-controller) is a good working example how you can avoid binding problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here goes my solution. Let your model be as shown below.

```
public class CheckboxModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class MainModel
{
    public List<CheckboxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
}
```

And let your Controller `GET` Action be as shown below.

```
public ActionResult GetDatas()
{
    MainModel model = new MainModel();
    var list = new List<CheckboxModel>
    {
         new CheckboxModel{Id = 1, Name = "India", Checked = false},
         new CheckboxModel{Id = 2, Name = "US", Checked = false},
         new CheckboxModel{Id = 3, Name = "UK", Checked = false}

    };
    model.CheckBoxes = list;
    return View(model);
}
```

And `POST` Action be as shown below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostDatas(MainModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

The `View` should be as shown below.

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.MainModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostDatas","Home"))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxes.Count; i++)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CheckBoxes[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CheckBoxes[i].Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.CheckBoxes[i].Checked)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.CheckBoxes[i].Name)                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    }
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

`View` will be rendered as shown below.

[image]

When you select `India` and `US` and click on submit button, you will get POST parameters as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But we really need to take Hidden Fields?

Comment: To pass `Name` and `ID`, yes we need them.

Comment: Here we are passing the data from controller to view as list type. How to use Class as model in the same type?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: I am not getting `MainModel` in `WebApplication1.Controllers.MainModel`