# return list of objects from checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, checkbox

I'd like to return a list of Personnes from checked checkbox in my view and get it in my controller but selectedObjects count is always 0...

Here's my view with checkboxes:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Presence", "Evenement"))
{
    foreach (var p in Model.Personnes)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedObjects" value="@p" />
    }
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="Valider Presence" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Presence(List<Personne> selectedObjects)
{
    return View(selectedObjects);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CheckboxList in MVC3 View and get the checked items passed to the controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284395/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-view-and-get-the-checked-items-passed-to-the-controller)

Comment: You cannot bind a checkbox to a complex object (look at the html your generating!). You need to set the `value` attribute to a property of your model e.g. `value="@p.ID"` and the method needs to be `Presence(int[] selectedObjects)`

Comment: Thanks I manage to get the [] of Id's, now I've to find each person in db who matches the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind a checkbox to complex object. A checkbox only posts back a single value. Instead you need to bind to a property of `Personne`, for example, if it has a property `int ID`, then

```
foreach (var p in Model.Personnes)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedObjects" value="@p.ID" />
}
```

and then change the POST method signature to

```
public ActionResult Presence(int[] selectedObjects)
```