# ASP.NET MVC 4 and MVCContrib Grid: Render Checkbox for each TR and Post values in complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-4, mvccontrib-grid

**MVCContrib Grid:**

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Grid(Model.List).Columns(c =>
    {
        c.For(x => x.Id);
        c.For(x => x.Name);
        c.For(x =>Html.Partial("Partial/CheckBoxTemplate", new CheckBoxViewModel { Id = x.Id })).Named("Options");
    })

    @Html.SubmitButton()
}
```

**Controller Post Action:**

```
public ActionResult SendData(List<CheckBoxViewModel> list)
{
    return View();
}
```

**ViewModels:**

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool CheckBox { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public IPagination<Data> List { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CheckBoxViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.CheckBox)
```

All checkboxed are by default not checked.

How can I retrieve all checked checkbox values in my `SendData` action?

Comment: What's inside `Partial/CheckBoxTemplate.cshtml`? Also you seem to be binding to some `Name` property (`c.For(x => x.Name);`) but I can't see such property defined in your `CheckBoxViewModel`. Could you please show your real code?

Comment: But you are passing only the `Id` to your partial and you never set the boolean `CheckBox` property. Why aren't you using a view model? Why does your `ViewModel` uses an `IPagination<Data>` property instead of `IPagination<CheckBoxViewModel>` which would have made much more sense since you are attempting to generate checkboxes in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a real view model that will reflect the requirements of your view (displaying a grid containing for each row a checkbox, and displaying the id and name of the item and retrieving those values in a list in your postback action):

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool CheckBox { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public IPagination<CheckBoxViewModel> List { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your view strongly typed to this view model:

```
@model ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SendData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Grid(Model.List).Columns(c =>
    {
        c.For(x => x.Id);
        c.For(x => x.Name);
        c.For(x => Html.Partial("Partial/CheckBoxTemplate", x)).Named("Options");
    })

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

finally your partial could look like this:

```
@model CheckBoxViewModel

@{
    var index = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

@Html.Hidden("list.Index", index)
@Html.Hidden("list[" + index + "].Id", Model.Id)
@Html.Hidden("list[" + index + "].Name", Model.Name)
@Html.CheckBox("list[" + index + "].CheckBox", Model.CheckBox)
```

Now when the `SendData` action is invoked it will be passed the list of your view model.

Alternatively you could use the `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper presented in the [`following article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which would allow you to use the strongly typed versions of the helpers:

```
@model CheckBoxViewModel
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("list")) 
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.CheckBox)
}
```

Recommended further reading: [`Model Binding To A List`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Comment: There is one thing that is surprising me: Why is CheckBoxFor creating an additional input hidden field?

Comment: Because in HTML checkboxes do not send the value if the checkbox is not checked. So the ChekBox helper adds an additional hidden field with hardcoded `false` value. This way if the checkbox is not selected false will be bound to the boolean field of the view model and if the checkbox is checked, 2 values with the same name will be sent: true and false, and the first value will be bound.